# what does Spring Boot multiple modules project's classpath look like?

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a multi-modules project with Spring Boot, and it always confuse me that what does its class path look like .

My project looks like this:

```
project
|-- module1
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           |-- /params/applicationContext.xml
|   |           
|   `-- pom.xml
|-- module2
|   |-- src
|   |   `-- main
|   |       |-- java
|   |       |   `--GetPropertyUtils.java
|   |       `-- resources
|   |           `-- /params/batch-jobs.xml
|   `-- pom.xml
```

If Module1 is my web module and module2 is a CommonUtil module,

When the server is started, are two property files(batch-jobs.xml and applicationContext.xml)' classpath the same(which are /resources/params)?

Ist there any document I can learn from?

Comment: you can very easy check it. just compile your project and then open the jar file with WinRar WinZip etc.